# Synology running docker & Portainer MacVlan Setup

Tags: docker, synology, portainer, macvlan

I recently started Using Docker&Portainer on my Synology. However all containers I Create use my Synology ipadres just a different port.
I want to setup a MacVlan through Portainer I am able to create the network only containers that use it have no acces to the Ethernet

Here are the steps I take;
First I ssh in to my Synology and enter the following comand
ifconfig | grep eth
[ifconfig | grep eth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBC7z.png)
Than I create the config using ovs_eth0 (I am able to use eth0 but when trying to create a container using the macvlan it does not work and I get a error 500 message)
[macvlanconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EnpD.png)
Than I create the actually network using the config network above.
[creating the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05QMJ.png)

This all works but when I assign the network to a container it has nog Ethernet acces.
What am I missing?

I can Hardly find any documentation so there might be a simpler solution.
I just want to be able to assign a ip address to my container that show up in my network instead of being on the same ip adres that my nas is on.

Used both eth0 and ovs_eth0.

When Trying to create a ipvlan it says operation not supported
[Trying to create ipvlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNt11.png)

Probably missing something but I can't figure it out myself

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a macvlan-template:
Looks like you're using the wrong network-driver. If you want to create a macvlan, you have to use the macvlan-driver.
Insert your prefered Subnet - /16 or /24 - depending on your needs.
Set your gateway - and set the IP-Range.
Use the Confighuration Field - click and that's all.

In the next step create the vlan - give it a name - again chosse the macvlan-driver an click Creation - there you go.

Comment: That what I did but when I add this network to a container the container itself has no internet.